# Building GDAL with libcurl support on Debian Linux

Tags: gdal, ubuntu, curl, linux-mint

Does anyone know how to build GDAL with libcurl support on Debian Linux (specifically LinuxMint and/or Ubuntu)?

After following build instructions [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnUnix) and tip from @EvilGenius below, I'm specifying the path to libcurl with this command:

```
./configure --with-curl=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

and I've also tried:

```
./configure --with-curl=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

**EDIT:** I've built on a machine with PostGIS installed, for what it's worth, but I'm still not getting CartoDB as a data format in the list of supported formats.

**Is there a way to check if GDAL was indeed built with libcurl support?**

Comment: The Debian GDAL packages appear to have cURL [support built in by default](https://buildd.debian.org/status/fetch.php?pkg=gdal&arch=i386&ver=1.11.2%2Bdfsg-3&stamp=1440763579) (search for 'cURL Support') and I believe it's built by default [as long as you have the proper libraries installed](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnUnix). Are you using a package/compile that you are having issues with?

Comment: @EvilGenius updated my question with some errors I'm getting... thanks again!

Comment: Anything prefixed with PQ is generally related to PostgreSQL. Make sure you have all your libs (-dev packages) installed or disable that support.

Comment: Ah right I think this is the problem that I am trying to install this from a client machine, rather than one with PostgreSQL installed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of those commands are wrong. It should be something like,

```
./configure --with-curl=/usr/bin/curl-config
```

`curl-config` is an executable which provides details on the curl version and locations of libraries, etc.

You can get this information by typing,

```
./configure --help|grep curl
```

But as EvilGenius says, you shouldn't need this command at all. Make sure curl is actually installed, of course.

**MB Edit:**

The correct libcurl installation syntax is:

```
apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

(once I had that installed, the config option above worked great and the installation allowed the CartoDB format to show up)